# How to match the biggest digit in regex

Tags: java, regex, integer

I have some pdf files in my downloads folder with a particular string pattern.I need to take the latest saved file.

My code is

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String directory=System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Downloads";
        File dir=new File(directory);
        for(File file:dir.listFiles())
        {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".pdf"))
            {

                String res=file.getName();
                match(res);
                //System.out.println(file.getName());
            }
        }

    }

    private static void match(String res) {
String pattern="[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]CR[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-[A-Z]-[0-9] \\(\\d+\\).pdf";
        Pattern r=Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m=r.matcher(res);
        if(m.find())
        {
            System.out.println("******* Match *********"+m.group());
        }
        else
        {

            System.out.println("******No match*******");
        }
```

}

And my output is like this

```
******* Match *********F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (5).pdf
******* Match *********F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (6).pdf
******* Match *********F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (7).pdf
```

Now I need to find the file which has the greatest number inside the braces ().So In this case I need

```
******* Match *********F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (7).pdf
```

Here how to match the greatest integer in regex?

thanks

Comment: Regex is not intended for this kind of problems. Just do it in code.

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov Then can I able to sort this??

Comment: Can't you just check the last write time or creation time on the files?

Comment: @ThaMe90 Is that possible to check via code?

Comment: Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getLastModifiedTime%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...%29)

Answer (score 2):

A simple strategy may be to retrieve the digit in parenthesis, to fill some sorted map where the mapping would be digit -> filename, and finally to get the filename associated to the greatest digit. I don't think it's possible simply with a REGEX.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer?I'm really new to regex

Answer (score 2):

You can add a group to your regex, and and a counter to keep the number:

```
int greater = 0;
String greaterFile = "";
String pattern="[a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9]CR[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]-[A-Z]-[0-9] \\((\\d+)\\).pdf";
                                                                                               //^^^^^^^^
Pattern r=Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m=r.matcher("F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (7).pdf");
if(m.find())
{
    System.out.println("******* Match *********"+m.group());
    int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    if (number > greater)
    {
        greater = number;
        greaterFile = m.group();
    }
}
else
{
    System.out.println("******No match*******");
}
System.out.println("Greater number is " + greater + " for " + greaterFile);
```

Notice that I did not escape the `()` in `\\((\\d+)\\).pdf`, this is because of their function in the expression, they define a group.

I can later retrieve the group using its index, knowing that the group `0` is the entire match, the next group, `1`, is our number.

This is for one file, but you can easily transpose it to your context.

Edit regarding your regex, it can be simplified like this:

```
String pattern="[a-zA-Z]\\d{2}CR\\d{4}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[A-Z]-\\d \\((\\d+)\\).pdf";
```

`\\d` means a number and `{n}` means the previous expression `n` times.

Comment: It is throwing `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: No group 1`

Comment: I also simplified your regex if that's something you are allowed to modify.

Comment: My output now is like this `******* Match *********F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (5).pdf
Greater number is 5 for F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (5).pdf
******* Match *********F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (6).pdf
Greater number is 6 for F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (6).pdf
******* Match *********F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (7).pdf
Greater number is 7 for F90CR0010-HBR-C-4 (7).pdf
******No match*******
Greater number is 0 for 
******No match*******
Greater number is 0 for 
******No match*******
Greater number is 0 for `

Comment: *This is for one file, but you can easily transpose it to your context.*, try to understand what happens, of course it won't keep the greater number inside the function's scope.

Comment: Isn't this overly complicated just to find out which file is older or newer than another file?

Comment: @ThaMe90 Yes.I'd try that FileTime as per your comment on my question

Comment: Regexes are incredibly powerful tools in certain situations when dealing with text from a document to find specific parts of text. Of course you can also use them for checking filenames, but due to the complexity of some filenames (such as yours), the regexes needed will become extremely (and unnecessarily) complicated. There are better ways. ;)

Comment: Absolutely, however I admit I did not try to understand the problem in its own, but yes if this code was needed for hat purpose, it's surely not the better way.